# How to make Fragments for each Swipe Tab in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

Hello I amtrying to develop app with Navigation Drawer and Swipe Tabs and I made like this in picture but here all tabs are located in one fragment can I divide and make fragment to each other tab(item 1,item 2...) inside can you help me make fragment to ech other(item 1,item 2...) and how and where add thanks[image]

```
private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

public ScreenOne() {
}

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_one, container, false);

return rootView;
 }

  @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());

// Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be 
// done AFTER the ViewPager has had it's PagerAdapter set.
mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}

 // Adapter
 class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

/**
 * Return the number of pages to display
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 10;
}

/**
 * Return true if the value returned from is the same object as the View
 * added to the ViewPager.
 */
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return o == view;
}

/**
 * Return the title of the item at position. This is important as what
 * this method returns is what is displayed in the SlidingTabLayout.
 */
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Item " + (position + 1);
}

/**
 * Instantiate the View which should be displayed at position. Here we
 * inflate a layout from the apps resources and then change the text
 * view to signify the position.
 */
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // Inflate a new layout from our resources
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
            container, false);
    // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
    container.addView(view);

    // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

    // Return the View
    return view;
}

/**
 * Destroy the item from the ViewPager. In our case this is simply
 * removing the View.
 */
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
}  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [Fragment Pager Adapater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) instead of a normal PagerAdapter. Check the documentation, it has a very complete working example.

Comment: will it work with my screen one fragment because it need a FragmentAktivity

Comment: Yes, it will work. As long as you use the child fragment manager you should be fine. Basically, replace this line `mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());` by `mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());`

Comment: it means that i should change Screen one to FragmentAktivity then attach adapter?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what screen one is now. But yes, you need a FragmentActivity that has a fragment and in that fragment there is a viewpager with inner fragments.

Comment: I have MainActivity and in main Aktivity I have Navigation Drawer and when position one Fragment =new ScreenOne();and this is Screen One here but my MainAktivity is not Fragment Activity